# Coinciding induced topologies for subsets of the same space

Tags: general-topology

From Wilson Sutherland's book I have the following excercise;
**Given subsets $A\subseteq B$ of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, with $A\neq \emptyset$, let $\mathcal{T}_A,\mathcal{T}_B$ be the subspace topologies on $A,B$ induced by $\mathcal{T}$.

Prove that $\mathcal{T}_A$ coincides with the topology on $A$ induced by $\mathcal{T}_B$.**

This may be fairly straightforward, and perhaps I'm just not understanding the concept of "induced" topologies very well. I believe I am to show that;
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{T}_A &= \mathcal{T}_{B\odot A}\\
 \{A\cap U: U\in \mathcal{T}\}  &= \{A\cap V: V\in \mathcal{T}_B\} \\
       &= \{A\cap V: V\in \{B\cap U: U\in \mathcal{T} \}\}
\end{align*}
(I know the $\odot$ notation is not standard, it was just off the top of my head, to distinguish it from $\mathcal{T}_B$ meaning the topology on $B$ induced by $\mathcal{T}$ from $(X,\mathcal{T})$)

I'm not sure how to go about this; in an previous part of the excercise I proved that, if $(A,\mathcal{T}_A)$ is a subspace of $(X,\mathcal{T})$, and some set $V\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$, then the intersection $V\cap A$ is closed in $(A,\mathcal{T}_A)$. 
--- I believe this is actually a preposition that often comes up in topology textbooks? And that it is actually a biimplication; i.e. a closed subset of the topological subspace is always an intersection with a closed subset of $X$, but oddly enough we only proved the implication one way.

But either way, I don't quite see how to apply it to the above. To show that two induced topologies coincide, they should produce the same open sets, right? Then equivalently one could show them having the same closed sets (I believe)?

Comment: There is a more general fact and that is that the initial topology is transitive. The subspace topology can be seen as being the finest topology such that the inclusion is continuous which is the initial topology generated by the inclusion

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. The "finest topology" means what in this context? The one topology $\mathcal{T}_2$ being finer than another $\mathcal{T}_1$ iff $\mathcal{T}_1\subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$. So "finest" means the topology such that all other topologies are subsets? I'm also not certain what you mean by "such that the inclusion is continuous which is the initial topology generated by the inclusion"

Comment: yeah my bad I meant to say the least fine topology. So out of all the topologies that I can give $Y\subset X$ the subspace topology is the least fine out of the ones that make the inclusion continuous.

Comment: Ah. To be honest I still don't see how that solves the issue of showing that the two topologies here are equivalent. Either way, I'm hesistant to use it, since it's not stated in my book. \
I would have to show that $\mathcal{T}_A \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{B\text{ on }A}$ and vice versa. That is, either is "as fine" as the other. But I'm not sure how to go about this in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show both inclusions. Let $\tau_A=\{A\cap U:U\in \tau_x\}$ and $\tau_B'=\{A\cap U: U\in \tau_B\}$.

Assume $V\in \tau_A$ then by definition there is a $U\in \tau_X$ such that $V=A\cap U$ but $U\cap B\in \tau_b$ so we have $V=(A\cap B)\cap U=A\cap (B\cap U)$ since $A\cap B=A$. So $V\in \tau'_A$. So we showed $\tau_A\subseteq \tau'_A$

On the other hand if $V\in \tau'_A$ we have that there is a $U\in \tau_B$ such that $V=A\cap U$. But by definition of $\tau_B$ we have that there is a $W\in \tau_X$ such that $U=B\cap W$. So $V=A\cap (B \cap W)=A\cap W$ and therefore $V\in \tau_A$.   So $\tau_A'\subseteq \tau_A$

Comment: Ah, thanks for spelling it out for me like this. My brain was a tad fried after staring at the problem for so long.
Btw, I think you renamed $\tau_B'$ to $\tau_A'$ immediately?